# Ordering word problem

Tags: combinations

Three girls and three guy sit in a row. How many ways can they sit if all the guys want to sit together?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Group the guys and assume it is a single guy.

Then we get $4$ persons in total and they can be arranged in $4!$ ways.

The $3$ guys among themselves can be arranged in $3!$ ways.

Totally, $4! \times 3!$ possible arrangements.